# How to add erlang source file to elixir package release to hex

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix, hex-pm

I am using mix to build an Elixir library.

This library includes an erlang module, in the src directory.

When I require my library into a second project using a relative file path (i.e. I have the full source) it works correctly. I have just published this package to hex and when declaring it as a hex dependency in the same second project I get the error that the erlang module is not loaded.

[Tokumei 0.8.0 on hex.pm](https://hex.pm/packages/tokumei/0.8.0)

Comment: Can you post a link to the hex package?

Comment: Link added for hex package

Comment: Try adding `"src"` to https://github.com/CrowdHailer/Tokumei/blob/37bd99b1a5d51a01b3cf0e44fae0bcde4ae7cb58/app/mix.exs#L47.

Comment: That looks to be the answer. cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're [explicitly specifying](https://github.com/CrowdHailer/Tokumei/blob/37bd99b1a5d51a01b3cf0e44fae0bcde4ae7cb58/app/mix.exs#L47) the list of files to include in the package but the list does not contain `src`, which is why the files in `src` are not included. You can either add `"src"` to that list:

```
defp package do
  [files: ["lib", "mix.exs", "README*", "LICENSE*", "src"],
   ...
end
```

or you can remove that key entirely, which will make Hex use the default value of `:files` [which includes](https://github.com/hexpm/hex/blob/c61ecc1e7322713ea9cfeb05d0002c50bb2445af/lib/mix/tasks/hex.build.ex#L4-L5) many other files, including `src`.